# Multiple routes with same number of params in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My client wants two urls in website:

```
a) www.example.com/{cityname}-items.html 
b) www.example.com/{statename}-items.html
```

How do i code **two routes** for these two urls? First one list items in one city and second one list items under one state.

```
Route::get('{city}', 'CityController@searchCity');
Route::get('{state}', 'CityController@searchState');
```

When i do this? only first route works, since both have same number of params Client wants to do this without updating url

Comment: You cant, in that way. bcs when you come through url, route can not make any difference b/w city and state. To resolve this, at least you have to put some key like "/c/{city}-items.html" and "s/{state}-items.html" to differentiate b/w them.

Answer (score 1):

Basically : you can't. There's no way there for your system to figure it out when hitting for example

```
www.example.com/whashington-items.html
```

if you try to hit the state of whashington, of the city of whashington.

You should consider splitting your logic :

```
www.example.com/city/{name}-items.html
www.example.com/state/{name}-items.html
```

2 "endpoints" (or sort of), that sounds better I think.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Route::get('{cityOrState}-items.html', function($cityOrState){
    $city = City::find($cityOrState);

    if(is_null($city))
    {
        return App::make('CityController')->searchState($cityOrState);
    }

    return App::make('CityController')->searchCity($cityOrState);
});
```